# How can we write this number amount ?

Tags: orthographe, nombres

I don't know French, and just need to write this amount in French: `129,29 Euros`

How can this value be represented with words?

Comment: Answer [here](http://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/nombre/129%2C29.html) : cent vingt-neuf virgule vingt-neuf. Type whatever figure you need in [the box](http://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/frnombre.php) and it will be translated into letters. That is how you say it, but if you write it as an amount on a cheque you replace "virgule" by "et" and you have to write euros and centimes (or cents, both are allowed). **Cent vingt-neuf euros et vingt-neuf centimes**.

Comment: @Laure Les deux sont admis, mais *centime* est recommandé en langage courant (par le JO, cette fois ;) ). http://www.culture.gouv.fr/culture/dglf/cogeter/2-12-97-euro.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value 129,29 € may be pronounced/written “*cent vingt-neuf virgule vingt-neuf euros*”, however for a money amount (especially on a check) you usually split the monetary unit (euro) from its subdivision (cent, “*centime*” in French) in the phrasing:

> cent vingt-neuf euros et vingt-neuf centimes

(“*cents*” instead of “*centimes*” will also be completely understood/accepted.)

You can use [this service](http://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/frnombre.php) on lefigaro.fr to obtain the wording of any number.

Comment: I disagree with *cents*, I very rarely heard it. And it can also be ambiguous: *800,08 €* gives *huit cent euros et huit cents*. With *centimes* it's easier to understand.

Comment: Sure, _centimes_ is more correct strictly speaking, and _cents_ is indeed rarer, but I saw it several times on checks (perhaps used as a shorthand) and it never annoyed anyone. Obviously for somewhat ambiguous cases it's even more useful to stick to _centimes_.

Comment: "cent" is the international naming. "centime" is the official naming in France. http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centime_%28euro%29

Comment: I don't know about quebec and the bilingual culture, but i've never heard or read any french using cents instead of centime. I don't think it's a good advice to pronounce or write "virgule" for a money ammount

Comment: If you write that amount for a Belgian recipient, you should use "cents" as "centimes" has disappeared with the Belgian franc.

Answer (score 0):

When it is for cheque writings, "cents" is not required to be writed in letters.

You can write `129,29 €` in the numeric part and

`Cent vingt-neuf euros et 29 cents` in the alpha part.